# Oversized images when saving on Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

So, I'm doing some print stuff and when I export it as JPG or any other format that's not PDF, there's a huge white space that changes the final image size! Let's say I have a 4cm x 4cm image, once I save it, it looks like this

[image: Look at it in a new tab] **What's the problem?**

Comment: Use safe for web and in image size disable clip to artboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be 2 reasons for this:

1. You have another object – it could be white or clear – on the bottom right
2. You have selected 'use artboards' in your export option and your artboard is much bigger than your art.

If it's 1 (more likely) go see if there's another object. Look in your layers pallet to see if it might be locked or hidden. If you still can't find it, you can make your artboard rea

Comment: Well, it was the first one. I really hate sublayers because of this.. Anyways, thanks!